# Invalid hook call error when trying to set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a scenario where I am forced to call a trigger method to show a modal from two different places, one using a hotkey combination and another by clicking on a toolbar button. In order to do so I have the following code, where I call the `triggerCustomLinkModal` to set the state but then I am hit with the `Invalid Hook call error`.

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react"
import { Dialog } from "@blueprintjs/core"

const useLocalState = () => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false)

  const setState = useCallback((state) => {
    setIsShown(state)
  })

  const getState = useCallback(() => {
    return isShown
  })

  return {
    setState,
    getState
  }
}

export const CustomLinkModalUI = () => {
  const { getState } = useLocalState()

  return (
    <>
      <Dialog isOpen={getState()} />
    </>
  )
}

export const triggerCustomLinkModal = () => {
  const { setState } = useLocalState()

  setState()
}
```

Comment: You can't use hooks [outside React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding from Chris answer in the comments ( You can't use hooks outside [React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).  -> so you can't call `useLocalState()` inside `triggerCustomLinkModal` since `triggerCustomLinkModal` is not a React component ):

You don't really need the useCallback hook or even the functions itself. Aaccording to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) :

> Note
>
> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

This also means that using `useCallback` hook to set a state it doesn't really make sense (because useCallback role is just to return `a memoized callback`)

What you basically need is a state set up in the closest parrent component and pass the `setIsShown` as a prop as well as the `isShown` function.

Your current implementation, even if it weren't for the error, it wouldn't refer to the same state since on each `useLocalState()` you are initializing a fresh new state (so you are not pointing to the same state in `CustomLinkModalUI` and `triggerCustomLinkModal`)

Comment: I need to show the modal by a trigger as the source of the action is on two separate components. So what would be the best approach if not by passing props?

Comment: The best would be passing props. Do you have any reason to avoid props?

Comment: Actually its a WYSIWYG editor built on @udecode/plate. In that we have a toolbar that is a child of the main editor plate. Now the hotkeys work on the main editor plate component, whereas the toolbar is a separate component. It would have been great if the state could have been shared.

Comment: But can't you declare the state in the main editor plate and just send the `state` and the `setState`  as props to the `toolbar` ? By doing so the state will be shared.